# How can I fix this/make it a drain for washing machine?

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine

I've got a Michigan basement and the former owners rigged up the washing machine to an old outlet that appears to be a broken pipe, as pictured. The metal piece with the opening has a 2" inside diameter and 4" outside diameter. How can I alter this so it's properly sealed and okay to run a washing machine hose to? Should I modify anything or just attach some PVC?

[image: Outlet]

Edit: the pipe sits in the "upper" ledge of the Michigan basement. If you aren't familiar, a Michigan basement has walls that form a sort of zig zag. The washing machine is on the basement floor, behind it is a half wall, then a ledge. [image: basement]

Comment: That big piece is a clean out Y.  You probably want a new cap with a 2 inch pipe or hole to place pipe in.  I think most washers want a three or four foot pipe straight up for an air break(the washer does not suck water back in).  You probably also need a P-trap at the bottom to block sewer gas from coming up.

Comment: Can you post a wider photo showing more of the pipe above the floor, and if possible the location of the washer?   The answer seems easy but it would help to see that there is nothing preventing the obvious thing.   Roughly, replace that cleanout cap with a cleanout cap, and tie in to the drain a foot or two higher.

Comment: Yeah somehow I forgot about that, the reason I posted was the space constraints.